# Receiving JSON encoded information from another program to my GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, networkstream

I need to receive JSON information from another program and display it in my GUI. The current code I have just crashes the program. I have researched the problem I have for about a week now and I can't seem to find a solution.

This piece of code should receive the information from the program and should deserialize the data.

```
public void TelemetryUpdateReceived()
{
        TelemetryUpdate tUpdate;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        while (client != null)
        {
            int num_bytes = 0;
            num_bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, num_bytes);
            DisplayMessages(message);

            tUpdate = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<TelemetryUpdate>(message);
            data.Altitude = tUpdate.Altitude;
            data.Elevator = tUpdate.ElevatorPitch;
            data.Pitch = tUpdate.Pitch;
            data.Speed = tUpdate.Speed;
            data.Throttle = tUpdate.Throttle;
            data.VerticalSpeed = tUpdate.VerticalSpeed;
            data.WarningCode = tUpdate.WarningCode;
        } 
}
```

I also have a class to get and set the data.

```
class getData
{
        public double Altitude { get; set; }
        public double Speed { get; set; }
        public double Pitch { get; set; }
        public double VerticalSpeed { get; set; }
        public double Throttle { get; set; }
        public double Elevator { get; set; }
        public int WarningCode { get; set; }
}

struct TelemetryUpdate
{
        public double VerticalSpeed;
        public double Throttle;
        public double Altitude;
        public double Speed;
        public double Pitch;
        public double ElevatorPitch;
        public int WarningCode;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add a error message screenshot [Error Message I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtcBr.png)

EDIT 2: This is the code I use to display the data

```
private void DisplayMessages(string messageJ)
    {
        ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { messageJ });
        this.lstBoxLatestData.Items.Insert(0, listViewItem);
        if (this.lstBoxLatestData.Items.Count > 40)
        {
            lstBoxLatestData.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxLatestData.Items.Count - 1);
        }

    }
```

After setting a breakpoint, this is a sample of the JSON that raised the exception with an "Invalid JSON primitive" message:

```
{"Altitude":-1.2874016160000004,"Speed":0,"Pitch":0,"VerticalSpeed":0,"Throttle":0,"ElevatorPitch":0,"WarningCode":0}
{"Altitude":-1.2874016160000004,"Speed":0,"Pitch":0,"VerticalSpeed":0,"Throttle":0,"ElevatorPitch":0,"WarningCode":0}
```

Comment: Can you add the string data you are getting under message

Comment: The _"The current code I have just crashes the program."_ is a poor description of an error. Do you get an Exception? If so, what error message? What information (callstack) does it have? What `message` caused that code to fail?

Comment: Why do you assume the buffer is 256 bytes?

Comment: @Ygalbel op later uses `num_bytes`, so far so good, but I wonder if all needed data for the serialization fits in those 256 bytes, that is why I asked what input caused the error.

Comment: If you share the data, it will easier for us to help you. We will be able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @Ygalbel The data I get comes in the format of {"Throttle":60,"ElevatorPitch":5}

Comment: @bradbury9 I have added a screenshot of the error I get.

Comment: @bradbury9 I have also added the code of how the data is displayed on my GUI

Comment: In your screenshot I see at the end truncated text, could you edit your question and paste the content of `string message` variable?

Comment: @bradbury9 I can't paste the content of the variable as it changes each time, as i'm reading the data from another program, I can however provide you the format that the data comes in. The format is {"Altitude":0,"Speed":0,"Pitch":0,"VerticalSpeed":0,"Throttle":0,"ElevatorPitch":0,"WarningCode":0}

Comment: Set a `try-catch` block in your code, put a breakpoint in the `catch` and look at the content of that variable. The format looks fine.

Comment: @bradbury9 This is what is in the variable when it is at the breakpoint "{\"Altitude\":-1.2874016160000004,\"Speed\":0,\"Pitch\":0,\"VerticalSpeed\":0,\"Throttle\":0,\"ElevatorPitch\":0,\"WarningCode\":0}{\"Altitude\":-1.2874016160000004,\"Speed\":0,\"Pitch\":0,\"VerticalSpeed\":0,\"Throttle\":0,\"ElevatorPitch\":0,\"WarningCode\":0}{\"Altitude\":-1.2874016"

Comment: Added an answer with why it fails and couple of alternatives. IMHO it looks like you are receiving duplicated information and because of it it is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid JSON. It should either be:

- A single element

```
{
    "Altitude":-1.2874016160000004,
    "Speed":0,
    "Pitch":0,
    "VerticalSpeed":0,
    "Throttle":0,
    "ElevatorPitch":0,
    "WarningCode":0
}
```

- An array of objects.

Note: In this case you should also change your `C#` struct to store an array, recent Visual Studio versions do have a "Paste JSON as classes" feature you could use

```
[
    {
        "Altitude":-1.2874016160000004,
        "Speed":0,
        "Pitch":0,
        "VerticalSpeed":0,
        "Throttle":0,
        "ElevatorPitch":0,
        "WarningCode":0
    },
    {
        "Altitude":-1.2874016160000004,
        "Speed":0,
        "Pitch":0,
        "VerticalSpeed":0,
        "Throttle":0,
        "ElevatorPitch":0,
        "WarningCode":0
    }
]
```